# ASP.NETCORE installing/updating packages give compatibility error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, sendgrid

I've got an ASP.NETCORE web application and I am trying to install the SendGrid package on it using visual studio, but it gives me an error saying one or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreAPP, Version=v1.1. 
Then I noticed the current packages had updates available and I tried to update the current packages but it still gave me the same error.

This is the error message:

```
Package Microsoft.Composition 1.0.27 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 
(.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package Microsoft.Composition 1.0.27 supports: 
portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile259)
One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1.
```

This is my project.json file:

```
{
"Netcoreapp1.0": {

"dependencies": {
  "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
    "type": "default",
    "version": "1.1.0"
  },
  "MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore": "7.0.6-ir31",
  "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.2.306",
  "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "2.0.0",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.0",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
  "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.1.0",
  "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
  "Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql": "1.1.1-prerelease-10016",
  "Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime.CoreCLR": "1.1.0",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.1.0"
},

"tools": {
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
    "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
  }
},

"buildOptions": {
  "emitEntryPoint": true,
  "preserveCompilationContext": true
},

"Frameworks": {
  "Net461": {},
  "Netcoreapp1.0": {
    "Dependencies": {
      "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
        "Version": "1.0.1"
      }
    },
    "Imports": "dnxcore50"
  }
},
"runtimes": {
  "win7-x64": {},
  "ubuntu.14.04-x64": {}
},

"publishOptions": {
  "include": [
    "wwwroot",
    "**/*.cshtml",
    "appsettings.json",
    "web.config"
  ]
}
}
}
```

I am very very new to this and new to programming in general. Let me know if you need to look at more of the files from the project.
Thanks!

Comment: Which Nuget package are you trying to install?

Comment: I was trying to install Sendgrid when I got this error. But when I tried to update the currently initialled packages it game me the same error.

Comment: Which version of SendGrid you are using ?